# How to modify sklearn's pipeline visualization (what it used instead of __repr__ and __str__?)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, visualization, pipeline

Sklearn has a nice and rather unknown visualization that can be activated via `sklearn.set_config(display='diagram')`. I am trying to customize the output of the visualization and cannot figure out how the html output is generated. I know python's magic methods __str__ and __repr__ that can be used to create a textual representation of some object. I expected that __repr__ would be used to create the html output. To test this assumption, I overwrote the method to output the string "repr". As the following code and its output show, the __repr__ method is called but obviously it is not used as entrypoint for the html generation since that would result in a single output: "repr".

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

sklearn.set_config(display='diagram')


class DummyPipeline(Pipeline):
    def __repr__(self, *args):
        print("repr")
        return "__repr__"

    def __str__(self, *args):
        print("str")
        return ("__str__")


class DummyEstimator(BaseEstimator):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        pass

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        pass


DummyPipeline(steps=[('first_estimator', DummyEstimator()), ('second_estimator', DummyEstimator())])
```

This returns:
[image]
The question is therefore: Which method would I need to change the html representation?

Answer (score 0):

The main method is `sklearn.utils.estimator_html_repr`; see its [API docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.estimator_html_repr.html#sklearn.utils.estimator_html_repr),  the [User Guide](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/utils/_estimator_html_repr.py), and the code in [this file](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/71f7085dae11a0a7091a3c07df4bc5bc8b119fe6/sklearn/utils/_estimator_html_repr.py#L288).

That function calls `str(estimator)`, so that is where most estimators generate their outputs for the html (as you see in your example, with the `DummyPipeline` printing `"__str__"`).  Meta-estimators (like the pipeline) get examined in [this section](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/71f7085dae11a0a7091a3c07df4bc5bc8b119fe6/sklearn/utils/_estimator_html_repr.py#L93) of the code, and `Pipeline` itself gets some special treatment in its `_sk_visual_block_` method [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b3ea3ed6a09fe774dfc5160a65172b1bacbb2a82/sklearn/pipeline.py#L646).

So, depending on what exactly you want to change, there are many places you might need to do so.  I have monkey-patched the `_STYLE` constant from the `estimator_html_repr.py` file before; since there are not too many composite estimators, this can work well enough.